# How to attach a number to a movie clip

Tags: actionscript-2, flash-cs3

This is what I am trying to achieve but I do not remember the syntax in AS2 if someone could please help.

```
public function highlightCan() {
    var glowId = String(this);
    var newId = glowId.substring(47);
    trace ("newId : " + newId); 
    new Tween(_parent._glow["newId"], "_alpha",    
    mx.transitions.easing.None.easeNone, _parent._glow0._alpha, 100, 2, false);
}
```

The newId, is what I am trying to attach to _glow.

If I hard code this value i.e. _glow0 or _glow1, this works but this value needs to be dynamic, in order to get the rollover state working. per highlightCan();

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`public function highlightCan(`**`id:Number`**`) {`

```
 var glowId = String(this);
    var newId = glowId.substring(47);
    trace ("newId : " + newId); 
    new Tween(_parent._glow["newId"], "_alpha",    
    mx.transitions.easing.None.easeNone,
```

**`eval("_parent._glow"+id)._alpha`**`, 100, 2, false);
    }`

when you call the `highlightCan()` you must send the `ID number` e.g.:  `highlightCan(2)` will make transition on `_parent._glow2._alpha`